# What does it mean when a Regex starts with | ?

Tags: php, regex

Here is an example:

```
return preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?
                  (/.*)?$|i', $url);
```

Here is another:

```
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U", "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>", $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Isn't | a OR in Regex? What does it mean when a regex starts with a | ?

Comment: Example is from : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php actually.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily negate @AndyRay's statement ;)

Comment: Which doesn't prevent this is an idiotic thing to do. The convention is to use `/` as delimiters. And unfortunately PHP has no `Regex` object which would allow you to do without delimiters at all.

Comment: Sure, I did not want to argue actually. It is just, because it is on php.net, I thought it would be best practice.. It seems it is not.

Comment: You might like to look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html.

Comment: The other example is from : http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html ( Exposing the idiots I guess.. )

Comment: For anyone looking for a good Regex tutorial: http://regexone.com/

Comment: @KorayTugay better buy a book "Mastering Regular Expressions" by Jeffrey Friedl.

Comment: Its neither best or worst practice. You just need to know its a regex meta character. if your regex does not contain any meta character you can use it as delimiter. also you can use it as meta character by escaping with a single \

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im and how would you escape the `|` as the OR operator?

Comment: What is the U and the i at the end of the expressions?

Comment: @meze if the regex contain `|` as meta-character dont use it. a regex containing no `|` meta-character can be delimited with `|`. This vertical bar offers visual comfort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's using it as the regex delimiter which is an **extremely bad idea** as it prevents it from being used as the OR operator.

While it does make sense not to use `/` when dealing with URLs or anything else where slashes are often used (as every normal `/` would have to be escaped as `\/` in that case) it's usually much better to use e.g. `#` or `~` as the delimiter since those are normal characters in the regex itself.

Comment: Heh it's rarely used for anything unless you have strings containing temperature values. But possibly it's not available on querty keyboards? I remember it from years ago where I used to read german PHP tutorials *shame on me* - anyway, updated my answer to add a better alternative.

Comment: @ThiefMaster no, it isn't available and this is the first time I've seen it's used as a delimiter. The delimiter I use is `~` though, `!` prevents `(?!..)` from being used.

Comment: This is not a bad idea as long as the author knows using this as regex meta-characters needs escaping. The Regex provided by the OP shows that regex author knows it.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: This is wrong. It is **impossible** to use it as a meta character when using it as the delimiter. `preg_match('|^foo\|bar$|', 'foo|bar') === 1`

Comment: Yes. It s not possible. In fact I meant, **its safe to use if pattern does not contain any `|`**. `|` provides visual comfort.